# Positivity of a map in $(l^\infty(X))^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a set and $\varphi: l^\infty(X)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a linear map such that

- $||\varphi||=1$
- $\varphi(1_X)=1$

I am trying to prove that $\varphi(f)\ge 0$ for all $f\ge 0$, but all my approaches have failed so far.

Obviously, it is enough to prove that whith the additional condition $||f||\le 1$. In that case, using all the hypotheses, we get that $\varphi(f-1)\le 0$ and $\varphi(f+1)\ge 0$, but that does not seem to lead anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $\|\varphi\|=1$: if $0\le f(x)\le1$ for all $x\in X$, then $|\varphi(f)|\le1$. Then
$$
1=f+(1-f)\implies1=\varphi(f)+\varphi(1-f).
$$
Since $|\varphi(f)|\le1$ and $|\varphi(1-f)|\le1$, we must have $\varphi(f)\ge0$ and $\varphi(1-f)\ge0$.